# Casting a method to generic and non generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to be specific. I have a class called Result and a derived class from that, called Result

```
public class Result
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

These classes are used as return types in methods. For that, I've made this helper class:

```cs
public class ResultManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a success action
    /// </summary>
    public static Result Success()
    {
        var result = new Result { Success = true };

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a success action
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The object type to return with the result</typeparam>
    public static Result<T> Success<T>(T data)
    {
        var result = new Result<T> { Success = true, Data = data };

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a failed result
    /// </summary>
    public static Result Failed(string errorMessage = null, Exception exception = null)
    {
        // ... unrelevant code for the question

        return new Result { Success = false, Message = errorMessage };
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code above has two return types for Success, one if you don't want to return anything, and the other one, if you want to return something, but the Failed result will never return something. It is unnecessary, only an error message. 
This brings me to the following: When I want to make a method that can return Success with a return type, and failed without it, **how can I cast it to determine if the return type will be Success(generic) or Failed?**
Like this method here:

```cs
// The return type of the method is Result, because Result<T> derives from it
public static Result GetClipboardFromDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    // Search for items
    IEnumerable<ClipboardCopy> items = null;
    try
    {
        items = mClipboardCollection.Where(a => a.CopiedTime == dateTime);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This will return the class "Result"
        return ResultManager.Failed(
            "Something went wrong getting copies from the clipboard.", ex);
    }

    // If there is not values
    if (items.Count() <= 0)
        return ResultManager.Failed("There are not copies with that datetime.");

    // Return values
    // This will return the class Result<T>
    return ResultManager.Success(items.ToArray());
}
```

Actually, I'm doing this:

```cs
var clipboard2 = (Result<ClipboardCopy[]>)AClipboard.GetClipboardFromDateTime(DateTime.Today);
```

This will work If the return type is Result(generic) but if it is Return, it will crash with the exception:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to convert an object from type 'AdvancedClipboard.Desktop.Models.Result' to type 'AdvancedClipboard.Desktop.Models.Result`1[AdvancedClipboard.Desktop.Models.ClipboardCopy[]]'.'

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to convert an object from type 'AdvancedClipboard.Desktop.Models.Result' to type 'AdvancedClipboard.Desktop.Models.Result`1[AdvancedClipboard.Desktop.Models.ClipboardCopy[]]'.'

Comment: What is the point of the base class `Result`? As you can see yourself, the first thing to do with it is to cast it something else. What would you expect when you cast instance of base class to an instance of derived class when it, in fact, is not the derived class? C# designers decided to throw an exception (which you have shown us), considering it a programmer error.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek yes, but the second result: "There are not copies with that datetime." is not a programming error.

Comment: Why not just always return a `Result<ClipboardCopy[]>`? In some cases you might not have any Data but that shouldn't cause you a problem...

Comment: If I return Result<ClipboardCopy[]> I can't return the method Failed()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem that you are trying to convert upfront. Method return two type of result.

1. Success
2. Failed

I think you should do something like this.

```
var result = AClipboard.GetClipboardFromDateTime(DateTime.Today);

if(Result.Success)
{
   var dataResult = (Result<ClipboardCopy[]>) result;
}
```

if you don't want to do casting. There is another way but I don't suggest.

```
var result = AClipboard.GetClipboardFromDateTime(DateTime.Today);

if(result.Success)
{
    dynamic d = result.Data;
}
```

Above example dynamic you don't need to do casting but sametime you loose strongly type access of Data. It is mainly suggested when you do interop work. If you ok with loosing strongly type access then you can use it. One more thing also any error related to this will execute at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain me why "dynamic" is not suggested?

Comment: The second option is really useless, unless you remove the if statement.

Comment: Without checking if you do then it will fail at runtime because when failed result return it does not have Data.

Comment: In this case I'd say don't use dynamic because you should know the type of result so casting would be much more preferable.

Comment: That is why I gave the one of possible solution but written that I don't suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create something similar to Option / Maybe monad : ) 
You have few options to consider:

1. Put everything in the "parent"

   ```
   class Result<TValue>
   {
     TValue Value // throws if !HasValue
     bool HasValue 
     string ErrorMessage // throws if HasValue
   }
   ```

You can play around with derived types Some, None (Success, Failure) with appropriate constructors, or static "create" methods on the parent type + private constructors, or extension methods - whichever you prefer to create the "Success", "Failure" with. Functions returning this Result will always need to specify the generic parameter.

2. What you have + "pattern match" = "type switch" = cast on the callers' side
   i.e.

   ```
   var result = GetClipboardFromDateTime();
   switch(result)
   {
     case Success<ClipboardCopy[]>: ... break;
     case Failure: ... break;
     default: throw
   }
   ```

(C# 7 feature), alternatively

```
    if (result is Success<ClipboardCopy[]>)
    (result as Success<ClipboardCopy[]>)?.Value
```

etc.

3. Put success/error continuations/callbacks on the Result class

   ```
   Action<TValue> / Func<TValue, ?> onSuccess
   Action<string> / Func<string, ?> onError
   ```

   i.e.

   ```
   result.OnSuccess(value => /* do smthn /w value */);
   result.OnError(errorMsg => /* do smthn /w error msg */);
   ```

   (edit) Result impl:

   ```
   public void OnSuccess(Action<TValue> onSuccess) {
     if (!_hasValue) return;
     onSuccess(_value);
   }

   public void OnError(Action<string> onError) {
     if (_hasValue) return;
     onError(_errorMessage);
   }

   // alternatively
   public void Apply(Action<TValue> onSuccess, Action<string> onError) {
     if (_hasValue) {
       onSuccess(_value);
       return;
     }
     onError(_errorMessage);
   }
   ```

   Parent Result will need to have these methods. Can be done in various ways, (parent impl can be "do nothing" - Success & Failure children would override without checking for _hasValue etc). OnSuccess(), OnError(), Apply() don't have to be void, you can have `Result<TResult> OnSuccess<TResult>(Func<TValue, TResult> onSuccess)` (instead of `void` + `Action<>`) to be able to chain them (I wouldn't go this way in C# though :D).

In general, in C#, I would avoid "returning exceptions" / "error codes" etc. from methods in this fashion - I believe you should implement the "happy path" and have exception handling done via exceptions (if possible). I really like using this 'pattern' over TryGet() methods though.

Comment: This is a very good answer. Also, can you explain me the continuations/callbacks? I tried to make it but I could not. Maybe a link?

Comment: Have edited my answer. You may be interested in searching for 'C# Maybe monad', 'C# Option monad' to see what's possible

Comment: Very nice post. I can't understand why it have zero votes so far apart mine.

Comment: I've just discovered a [very nice post](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/20/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/) discussing a similar topic (posing a question why not to just go with a FP language directly :D)